# Login using Facebook SDK not working

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I'm trying to integrate Facebook login using >Facebook SDK LoginUsingLoginFragmentActivity

It is giving me error:

**MainActivityCode:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mFacebookLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_login);

        mFacebookLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFacebookLogin);
        mFacebookLogin.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnFacebookLogin:
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginIntoFacebookActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

**LoginIntoFacebookActivity.java**

```
public class LoginIntoFacebookActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private UserSettingsFragment userSettingsFragment;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.login_fragment_activity);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        userSettingsFragment = (UserSettingsFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.login_fragment);
        userSettingsFragment.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                Log.d("LoginUsingLoginFragmentActivity", String.format("New session state: %s", state.toString()));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        userSettingsFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

**Error Trace:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 13:46:28.087: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2901): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.LoginIntoFacebookActivity

E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at com.example.activity.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:31)

Line 31:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainLoginActivity.this, LoginIntoFacebookActivity.class);
```

**Manifest:**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activity.MainLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.activity.LoginIntoFacebookActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>
```

Comment: have you add facebook login activity in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @Haresh question updated, manifest file added

Comment: What is Package name of LoginIntoFacebookActivity?

Comment: @reiley,can you please post your login_fragment_activity layout code ?

Comment: @reiley: there is one sample available in facebook SDK "hellofacebookexample" import that sample match your code with it

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the AndroidManifest file has wrong information about which package LoginIntoFacebookActivity belongs to - there's a mismatch between the error trace you've posted and the manifest file.